# Android media player can't play ogg files

Tags: android, media-player, ogg

I'm using [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer) library to stream some audio files from my server. The problem is when I want to play **ogg** audio file with media player in android version **4.2.2** and it's ok when I play it in android **nougat**. It gives me this error while preparing **ogg** audio file:

> E/Tag: Prepare failed.: status=0x106
>
> E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
>
> E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
>
> E/MediaPlayer: stop called in state 0

Is there any alternative way to stream **ogg** format in all devices?
by the way there is no problem with playing **mp3** files in all android versions I'v tested.

Thank you ...

Answer (score 0):

First you should add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`
Then set data source, maybe:
`mp = new MediaPlayer();` 
`mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);` will help;

And of course prepare file before start:
`mp.prepare();`
`mp.start();`

Comment: I added the permission and I won't start media after it's prepared but still have the same problem. AudioManager.STREAM_RING didn't help either.